# Dynamic Menu Bar with Child Relation In MVC Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi i am student working on a Project in MVC i am Creating Dynamic Menu bar i retrieve Main Menu successfully but all child menus are shown in Contact Us Dropdown menu

```
 ---------------------------
 ID     ParentID    MenuName
 ---------------------------
  1       NULL       Home
  2       Null       Contact Us
  3         2        Address
  4         2        Place
  5         1        Index

 //html
 <div id="menu">
    <ul>            
    </ul>
 </div>

 //jquery code
function LoadMenubarSuccess(response) {
if (response != undefined && response != null && response.length > 0) {
    var IncidentData = "<ul>";
    $.each(response, function (index, Obj) {
        if (Obj.ParentMenuID == null || Obj.ParentMenuID == 0) {
            IncidentData += "<li>"
           + "<a href='" + Obj.Url + "'>" + Obj.MenuName + "</a>"

        }
        if (Obj.ParentMenuID == !null || Obj.ParentMenuID > 0) {
            IncidentData += "<ul>"+"<li>" + "<a href='" + Obj.Url + "'>" + Obj.MenuName + "</a>" +"</li>"+ "</ul>"                
        }
    });
    IncidentData +="</li>"+"</ul>";
    $("#menu").html(IncidentData.replace(/null/g, ' - '));
}
```

}

Comment: your loop is wrong.you are just appending it to something, and not using parentID anywhere to add child.

Answer (score 0):

The Loop is wrong.

You will have to first, sort your data to your needs.
In this case, it's probably best to loop through the items and attach the ones with parentID to the main item.

After that, start another loop which will create the actual menu.

```
// Sort could work like this
var menuList = [];
$.each(response, function(index, object) {

    if(object.ParentID != null && object.ParentID != undefined)
        menuList[object.ID].Children.push(object);
    else
        menuList[object.ID] = { Menu = object, Children = [] };
});
```

This way the data will be sorted to your needs (I did not test run this code).

After that, you can just do whatever you need with it. For example:

```
$incidentData = "<ul>";

$.each(menuList, function(index, parent) {

    $incidentData = $incidentData + "<a href='" + parent.Url + "'>" + parent.MenuName + "</a>";

    if(parent.Children.length > 0) {

        $.each(parent.Children, function (childIndex, child) {

            $incidentData = $incidentData + "<a href='" + child.Url + "'>" + child.MenuName + "</a>";

        });

    }

});

$incidentData = $incidentData + "</ul>";
```

Something like this should work.

You can see, we are sorting the data kinda like a tree.
Item has multiple parents and each parent can have multiple children.
This way, we don't have to do anything fancy. Perhaps you can change your source to do this for you?

Code is not tested. Adjust to your needs.